# cvCalcOpticalFlowBM error

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, opticalflow

I have been trying to use OpenCVs cvCalcOpticalFlowBM for optical flow calculations in my application. I am doing something similar to:

```
IplImage* velX1 = cvCreateImage(cvSize((beforeGray->width - blockSize.width + shiftSize.width)/shiftSize.width, (beforeGray->height - blockSize.height + shiftSize.height)/shiftSize.height), IPL_DEPTH_32F,1);
IplImage* velY1 = cvCreateImage(cvSize((beforeGray->width - blockSize.width + shiftSize.width)/shiftSize.width, (beforeGray->height - blockSize.height + shiftSize.height)/shiftSize.height), IPL_DEPTH_32F,1);
IplImage* velX2 = cvCreateImage(cvSize((beforeGray->width - blockSize.width + shiftSize.width)/shiftSize.width, (beforeGray->height - blockSize.height + shiftSize.height)/shiftSize.height), IPL_DEPTH_32F,1);
IplImage* velY2 = cvCreateImage(cvSize((beforeGray->width - blockSize.width + shiftSize.width)/shiftSize.width, (beforeGray->height - blockSize.height + shiftSize.height)/shiftSize.height), IPL_DEPTH_32F,1);

cvSetZero(velX1);
cvSetZero(velY1);
cvSetZero(velX2);
cvSetZero(velY2);

cvCalcOpticalFlowBM(beforeGray, afterGray, 1, blockSize, shiftSize, range, 0, velX1, velY1);
```

beforeGray and afterGray are IPL_DEPTH_8U single channel images of the same size. But when the last line execute I get the following exception:

```
OpenCV Error: Null pointer (NULL array pointer is passed) in cvGetMat
```

I am using OpenCV 2.4 and I cannot figure out why this isn't working. I have checked through the debugger that all input arguments aren't null. Anybody got any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like I got the arguments wrong. Should be:

```
cvCalcOpticalFlowBM(beforeGray, afterGray, blockSize, shiftSize, range, 0, velX1, velY1);
```